# Query using LIKE clause with a date string

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I work for a gun club and we are trying to find the total number of targets shot at during a specific year. The table contains totals from years 2000-2018 and I am trying to write a query that will look at the string for the date of the shoot which is in a format like this 2010-06-13 00:00:00.000 I just care about the year so I created this query:

```
SELECT SUM(ShotAt) AS TotalTargets
FROM MemberShootsC
WHERE GunClubNumber = 210015 AND ShootDate LIKE '2007-%%-%% 00:00:00.000'
```

If I run the query up to the AND clause it works and returns a total. However, I get a null value if I highlight the whole thing. I have tried variations of the string as well. Such as this '2007%' and this '2007-**-** %'

Not sure what I am missing. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Their LIKE implementations aren't fully compatible.

Comment: Why do you store dates as strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't convert to string to query for a year, use [`YEAR()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function instead:

```
SELECT SUM(ShotAt) AS TotalTargets
FROM MemberShootsC
WHERE GunClubNumber = 210015 AND YEAR(ShootDate)=2007 -- MySQL
```

You could also use a range query

```
SELECT SUM(ShotAt) AS TotalTargets
FROM MemberShootsC
WHERE GunClubNumber = 210015 AND ShootDate BETWEEN '2007-01-01' AND '2007-12-01 23:59:59.999'
```

**Note:** The above assumes that you do not store dates as strings. The function to use depends on RDBMS. In MS SQL Server you would use `DATEPART(year, ShootDate) = 2007`

Comment: Use `ShootDate >= '2007-01-01' AND ShootDate < '2008-01-01'` instead of `YEAR(ShoootDate) = 2007` since the former one prevents usage of indexes in both MSSQL and MySQL on the ShootDate column (if there is any) and performs an extra calculation which is not necessary.

Comment: @Pred Thanks for the comment! Edited.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help. Both of those options you gave me worked and they both returned the same value. For those who said the date wasn't a string but stored as a date since the above queries worked you were right. I'm new to SQL so just figuring things out. thanks again everyone for the help!